# E-mail address or contact form on web page to avoid spambots?

Tags: forms, email, captcha, spam

Hello I have a client that is using an email address for contact us. Spam bots have been harvesting their email address off the page. My preference is to use a contact form with a captcha. Is there a best practice for either or? I have read some similar posts that are supportive of both. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I always much prefer to at least have the option of writing emails in my email client. That way I at least have an audit trail of what I sent and when, and some level of confidence that it arrived.

One simple way to allow this, by hiding the mailto: link behind Captcha protection, is using Google's free [mailhide](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin#mailhide) service.

Comment: I'm not sure how easy it would be to include this into a CMS with many emails, that may not allow this. However, I have considered this by using js. I'll look at your example. calum_b

Comment: Hmm, they used to have a mailhide API for that sort of use case (dealing with multiple email addresses on the same website), but [that page appears to be gone](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/mailhideapi). Not sure if/how you'd implement something similar with the standard [reCaptcha APIs](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/intro).

Comment: I thought that there was a best practice to use the form for email. I have seen pros and cons on both sides. I was hoping for a definitive 'yes use the form' but it seems to be user preference.

Comment: There's rarely a definitive answer in UX :)

Comment: The definitive answer is the one that keeps your client happy. ;)

Answer (score 1):

How about good old

`email@<span style="display: none">false_email@</span>example.com` ?